# Angularjs adding service

Tags: angularjs, service

Html page code:

```
ng-click="removeCoupon(coupon.couponId)"
```

controller:

```
$scope.removeCoupon=adminService.removeCoupon(Id)
  .then(
            function(response) {
                hide_all_and_show_one_insideTab( 'successLog');
          $scope.log = "Coupon Id# " + Id + " successfully removed.";
            adminService.getCoupons()
        .then(
            function(response) {
                $scope.coupons = response.data;
            } );

            } );`
```

service:

```
     this.removeCoupon = function(Id){
     return $http.get(baseURL+"admin/removeCoupon/"+Id);
                                };
```

when i load the html, there is an eror 
"angular.js:13424ReferenceError: Id is not defined
    at new  (controller1.js:56)"

Someone can point my eror? before i did it without service and it worked just fine, so the ng-click successfuly transfer the coupon.couponId, now when i try to transfer all the server calling to a service, i get this eror.
the controller1 js.56 is the 1st line of the controler code i wrote here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it like this

```
$scope.removeCoupon = function(Id){
   adminService.removeCoupon(Id)
     .then(
            function(response) {
                hide_all_and_show_one_insideTab( 'successLog');
             $scope.log = "Coupon Id# " + Id + " successfully removed.";
               adminService.getCoupons()
          .then(
              function(response) {
                  $scope.coupons = response.data;
              } );

             } );
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? how do i do that?

Comment: There is a grey check icon below vote-up option please click on it